# ZXing freeze Android application

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code

I want to use ZXing library to scan QRcode but this library make my app freeze.

I've imported the ZXing project, added core.jar and create this activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
   if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
         String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
         // Handle successful scan
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // Handle cancel
      }
   }
}
```

I've edit my Manifest like that :

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.aristote.kalidea.ScanActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scan" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Last I've added permissions :

But, when I go on my ScanActivity, the application freeze, I can't do anything except kill the app, and I've no error message in my LogCat.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. You are trying to invoke a third-party app, Barcode Scanner. But you are intercepting the `Intent`. You're showing code that sends the `Intent`, but say the freeze is in your own code which you don't show. There's not enough info here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in fact I've done silliness.
I had impoted all the "Android" folder as new project that I used as library.
Finaly, I've restart from zero, import files founded in "android-integration" and use this code : https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Now, all is fine. I'll just search how to translate the warning message in current language.